# How to change favicon by code Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme, custom

How can I change the favicon of a Magento 2 store by code in my custom theme? without using admin backend interface.

Answer (score 1):

Magento will get the default favicon from `Magento_Theme` module.

**vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Favicon/Favicon.php**

```
 public function getDefaultFavicon()
 {
        return 'Magento_Theme::favicon.ico';
 }
```

So, in your custom theme, we can add `favicon.ico`:

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/web/favicon.ico**

If we want to know how Magento gets favicon in depth, we should take a look:

`--vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Favicon/Favicon.php`

```
public function getFaviconFile() { ... }
public function getDefaultFavicon() { ... }
protected function prepareFaviconFile() { ... }
```

`--vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php`

```
 public function prepareFavicon() { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

To override the default 16px x 16px favicon manually, add your custom favicon.ico in the /Magento_Theme/web/directory.

To add favicon icons of other sizes, take the following steps:

Add your icons in the /Magento_Theme/web/ directory.    In the /Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml layout    file specify the paths to the icons and their sizes.

For example, if you added a favicon-32x32.png icon and want it to be used as a 32px x 32px favicon, your default_head_blocks.xml would be like following:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Magento_Theme::favicon-32x32.png" rel="icon" sizes="32x32" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Please try below code**

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName**

**registration.php**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'VendorName_ModuleName', __DIR__);
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc**

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendorName_ModuleName">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Model\Favicon\Favicon" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Model\UpdateFavicon" />
</config>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Model**

**UpdateFavicon.php**

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Theme\Model\Favicon\Favicon as ParentClass;

class UpdateFavicon extends ParentClass
{
    /**
     * Get updated Favicon Icon
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDefaultFavicon()
    {
        return 'VendorName_ModuleName::favicon.ico';
    }
}
```

Once you've added the above file, move your favicon icon to this path with the name favicon.ico.

```
app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/favicon.ico
app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/web/favicon.ico
```

***Note: You need to remove the favicon icon from the store configuration. If the icon is not added to the store configuration, the above-added icon will be visible on the frontend.***
[image]