# How to change the favicon logo on the browser to open pdf files in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, pdf

I have checked on a few other websites and on my local version when i open the pdf file my mini icon changes. How i can open the pdf file but the icon remains the default on my website
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I will share it here if anyone needs it
Let's create a file called **favicon.ico** and add it to the index.php file the directory Magento is pointing to may have a cache and you need to delete it

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please try this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/371652/82670

Answer (score 0):

Add favicon.ico to root directory of your folder. After adding it, favicon.ico will automatically show in PDFs.

Note- In magento, you need to upload favicon.ico in pub folder